# @Streaming retrofit doesn't download file properly (proguard enabled)

Tags: android, retrofit

@Streaming retrofit doesn't download file properly in release version (proguard enabled) . Without @Streaming it works perfect in release version. With @Streaming it works in dev version without proguard

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
@Streaming
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileByUrl(@Url String fileUrl); }
```

Comment: Edit `proguard-rules.pro` file to keep `interface RetrofitInterface`.

Comment: I will check and update u man